# S60 Bar Code reading in my own application

Tags: barcode, s60, barcode-scanner

How can i go about using bar code reading capabilities with my S60 application?
Is there any free libs that i can use? or even comercial ones?

Thanks.

Comment: what programming language (C/C++, Java, Python) and which licenses are ok?

Comment: I prefer Java but i'm fine with either programing language.
And i would like to hear any option that comes to mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [J2ME code from ZXing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk#trunk/javame) will work on an S60, but is suboptimal for two reasons. J2ME can't access auto-focus on Nokia devices, which severely hampers barcode reading. Symbian code can, and will be much faster. However I don't know of decent Symbian code for this purpose. Maybe you can use the J2ME code as a starting point for a port.